# htaccess redirect www to non-www still puts .php extension in uri

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

*There is something I'm missing here :
[Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)*

**My goal:**

Redirect everything from www to non-www

**Current code in .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

**Current behaviour:**

Redirects everything from www to non-www but adds the php file extension ".php" in URIs (the php files do exists)

E.g:

> www.example.com/hello

redirects to

> example.com/hello.php

What should I do to avoid the php extension in the URI ?

Comment: Change this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]` to this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]`

Comment: Does this always happen? What if you do `example.com/hello`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: `example/hello` works fine.
Interesting enough, when removing everything but these two lines of code, the stated behaviour is the same

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Clear your browser cache if you'd used `301` previously. It caches it. Test using 302 until your rewrites are working then you can set it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why, it's working with the following code.

***The advice from @Panama-jack is a strong one : using 302 while working on htaccess rules is indeed the way to go before setting everything 301.***

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://iPutMyWholeUrlHere.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```